# Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected)

Tags: templating

I'm trying to build an array of values from 4 entries so I can lay them out in a comparison chart. I figured the best way to do this would be to add all of the values to a nested array. So I've set this up...

```
{% set plandata = {
        'membership-type' : {
            'title' : 'Membership Type',
            'url' : '',
            'price' : '',
            'items' : []
        }
    }
 %}
```

then I'm iterating through a field and trying to add them to the items portion like so...

```
{% for amenity in entry.availableAmenities %}
    {% set plandata.membership-type.items = plandata.membership-type.items|merge(amenity.title) %}
{% endfor %}
```

However I am getting a Template Error:  Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected).

Can anyone give me any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I see three problems here.

One of them is the `-` in `membership-type`. `plandata.membership-type` does not mean the membership-type field of plandata, but more something like `(plandata.membership) minus (type)`. So you will either want to use `membershipType` or `membership_type`, or the less readable twig [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function: `attribute(plandata, 'membership-type')`.

The second problem is that the twig [merge](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) filter operates on arrays, and you are passing it a string. This won't work: `|merge(amenity.title)`, this will: `|merge([amenity.title])`

The third problem is that the twig [set](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) assigns values to variables, and `plandata.membershipType.items` is not a variable. The only way (in twig) to "assign" to a field of an array is with the [merge](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) filter. So you will need something like this:

```
{# create your amenityTitles array #}
{% set amenityTitles = [] %}
{% for amenity in entry.availableAmenities %}
  {% set amenityTitles = amenityTitles|merge([amenity.title]) %}
{% endfor %}

{# merge those amenityTitles with membershipType (somehow preexisting) #}
{% set membershipType = membershipType | merge({items: amenityTitles})}

{# merge that membershipType with plandata #}
{% set plandata = plandata | merge({membershipType: membershipType}) %}
```

If you can figure out a less deeply nested structure than that `plandata` you will probably be happier given the limitations of twig.

Comment: Well here's what I'm trying to do. This is an existing site I just got assigned to work on not knowing anything about Craft or twig

There are 4 entries, a main "Membership" page that then has a list of amenities assigned to it. Then 3 entries that are the 3 different membership descriptions, each of these entries has amenities assigned to them. I am attempting to build a comparison chart with the main page in column 1, then checkboxes for matching amenities for the 3 membership columns. I figured iterating through the amenities and add them to arrays to kick them out would be best. Opinion?

Comment: Maybe just iterating through the amenities and kick them out, or iterate through them and use `{% set something %} ... {% endset %}` to capture the html and then `{{something}}` later to display it. You can create complex datastructures they way you are trying to in twig, but it is a total pain in the ass.